# Debugging using Valgrind

Tags: gdb, arm, valgrind, gdbserver

I have a cross compiled gdb and gdb server for arm-linux which I use to remote debug. Since I am encountering memory related issues I would like to try using "valgrind" with gdb.

Can anybody briefly explain how this works ? I have valgrind sources and when I cross compiled with **--target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi** the primary target still comes out for x86, what shoud be the configuration ?.

Thanks in advance

Praveen

Comment: You might have to configure using a little bit more options. E.g. see the file README.android that can give some hints about what options you might need. E.g. for android; both --host and --target options are needed.